# read pdf split while I load the entire file in html object tag

Tags: javascript, html

how view a pdf in html page by page while loading the all file, can you help me please?

How to read and view PDF files page by page while loading the whole file, I find documentation on this

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some more explanation, but it sounds like you are asking how to view a PDF in HTML one page at a time.

To do this you will need a server-side program to convert the PDF file to HTML and then serve the results a page at a time. The browser can't do this.

Look at the [JPedal PDF to HTML5](http://www.idrsolutions.com/html_products) project if you can use Java on your web server.

Comment: thank you very much, I try to do is read a pdf from an object tag in html, I want to display the first page of the pdf while loading all the files, I have heavy pdf and linger long to be shown on my website

Answer (score 0):

Fast Web View” restructures a PDF document for page-at-a-time downloading (byte-serving) from web servers. With Fast Web View enabled, the web server sends only the objects that are required to render the requested page rather than the entire PDF file. This option is especially important with large documents that can take a long time to download from a server. This means that even with a large file, the first page will be displayed almost instantly. Additionally, if you link to a page within the same PDF document, Acrobat will stop downloading the document in background and begin downloading the newly requested page.

When a PDF document is not enabled for Fast Web View, the entire file needs to be downloaded before Acrobat or Reader can display anything. This is why Reader or Acrobat appear to “hang” the browser on some PDF files. It’s not that Reader is slow to load or that the PDF file is bloated, the file has simply been created badly. Try each of the two links below to see the difference. The first link goes to a PDF file that has not been enabled for Fast Web View. The second link goes to a version of the same file except with Fast Web View enabled.

How to solve this problem from server